# How to properly print a vector of stacks?

Tags: c++

I have created a vector of stacks. Each stack contains an integer number. The code builds and runs but it gives "stackoverlfow" error in my overload function. I am sure its something ridiculously simple, which I don't see. I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::vector<std::stack<int>> &vectOfStacks)
{
    os << vectOfStacks;
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    int sum = 0;
    int sizeOfNum=0;
    std::stack<int> s;
    std::vector<std::stack<int>> vectOfStacks;

    std::cout << "How many numbers you want to add? " << std::endl;
    std::cin>>n;

    int* value = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter integers" << std::endl;

        std::cin >> value[i];



        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)     // same the integer one digit at a time into a stack
        {
            s.push(value[i] - '0');
        }

        vectOfStacks.push_back(s);  // push the stack for this number into vector

        std::cout << vectOfStacks;

        sum = sum + value[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Sum of the integers = " << sum <<std::endl;



    //addingLargeNumber(vectOfStacks);


    /*for (std::vector<std::stack<int>>::iterator it = vectOfStacks.begin(); it != vectOfStacks.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < vectOfStacks.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << vectOfStacks[i];
    }*/

    //std::cout << vectOfStacks[i];

    delete[] value;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have infinite recursive function. You call `operator <<`, and inside it you call `operator <<` with exactly the same parameter. There's no standard overload for neither vetor or stack, you have to implement that yourself.

Comment: `std::cout << "Length of array = " << sizeOfNum << "  =   "  << (sizeof(value) / sizeof(*value)) << std::endl;` is not going to give you a meaningful result.  Why aren't you using `n` since that is that you used for the size of the array?  Also, what aren't you just using a vector for `value`?

Comment: As Yksisarvinen noted, you have infinite recursion.  A more reasonable way to print any standard container (if elements are printable, etc) is to iterate over all elements of the container, print each element separately, possibly with extra whitespace so they can be read in more easily.   For a container of containers (as in a vector of stacks) that logic needs to be recursive.    Note that containers don't typically provide an ability to print themselves by default, precisely because it does not make sense to print everything that may be stored in a container.

Comment: A suggestion: figure out how to print the elements of a stack. Then figure out how to print the elements of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
os << vectOfStacks;
```

translates into

```
operator<<(os, vectOfStacks);
```

Consequently, you have infinite recursion in that function. You need to change the implementation to iterate over the contents of the `vectOfStacks` and stream them to `os` one by one.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::stack<int> const& st)
{
   if ( !st.empty() )
   {
      // Can't iterate over the contents of const std::stack. Need to make
      // a copy of the input object and use the copy to print the contents.
      std::stack<int> st_copy = st;
      while ( !st_copy.empty() )
      {
         int top = st_copy.top();
         st_copy.pop();
         os << top << " ";
      }
   }
   return os;
}

// Note the addition of const to the second argument.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::vector<std::stack<int>> const& vectOfStacks)
{
   for ( std::stack<int> const& st : vectOfStacks )
   {
      os << st;
   }
   return os;
}
```

Comment: You can't iterate over a stack, unfortunately

Comment: Oh right. Now I remember why I never use that ridiculous container adapter.

Comment: The input to *any* `operator<<` should be a `const` reference for non-POD types, so I would suggest changing 1) `std::stack<int>& st` to `std::stack<int> const &st` in `operator<<`, 2) `std::stack<int> st` to `std::stack<int> &st` in the `for` loop, and 3) making a copy of `st` inside of `operator<<` when `st` only is not empty.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for the suggestion. It made a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is on way (and `myPrint` can be changed into `operator<<` but it usually isn't a good idea to overload it for *raw* types from `std::` namespace):

```
std::ostream &myPrint(std::ostream &os, std::vector<std::stack<int>> const &vs) {
    os << "vec:\n";
    for (auto s : vs) {
        os << "\t(stack): ";
        while(!s.empty()){ os << s.top() << ' '; s.pop();}
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```